# Loading private pictures from flickr into imageView

Tags: android, flickr

I need to load some private pictures from flickr into imageViews. I tried to use flickrj-android but I don't really understand how it works. My guess is I need to get the oauth-token first. That I can do. But how do I proceed from there? I googled already but didn't find anything usefull.
All I want is a way to construct my URLs so I can load the pictueres into ImageViews.
Has anyone worked with flickr before and knows a good step by step tutorial?
It can't be that difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have questions about the whole flow from authorization to Flickr url construction, I suggest you have a look at the open source sample application [Android Photostream](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/09/android-photostream.html) which includes everything you need to create your own basic Flickr app. It's part of the [apps-for-android](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/) project.